# Debugging JavaScript for CRM For Phones

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I'm using Dynamics CRM For Phones. I get errors on phone which I don't get on the web application. This is obvious because there are separate methods for both.

However, if I have to debug the JavaScript for Phones, how can I do the same?
Is debugging possible for applications on Phones?

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: you can use chrome dev tools (device mode) to debug js

Comment: Hi, I'm using the Android app available in the Play Store and not the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so I had to post an answer instead. You could try remote debugging, if you manage to get it running. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging

Comment: this looks nice...! 
However, I wanted to be sure if this would work on CRM for Phones Android app ...............